# Error during cache:clear

Tags: symfony-3.4

When I run the `php bon/console cache:clear` I have this error :

> Invalid resource provided: "1.2"; Errors: [ERROR 1843] Element '{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}trans-unit': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is
>      'element-only'. (in /var/www/html/myproject/ - line 5, column 0)

I checked my xlf, files they look good, all the more I don't know witch one to check.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved even if I did not exactly understood what was the problem.

I tried to reinstall all my vendors by removing my vendor folder and executing `composer update`

The error does not appear any more